# Expandable listview in android with subgroup having child and another group

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I need to have a expandable group that can contain group as a child and other child member as a child, parallel to the group. I am able to add third level of group but not able to add dissimilar items that is group and child to the parent group.

I want some thing like:

> ParentGroup-->
>    -             - -------------Child 1
>   - - -------------Child 2
>   --------------->SubGroup 1-->
>   --------------------- -------------Child 1
>   -----------------------------------Child 2

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please brief your question more.

Comment: Try this  may help you https://github.com/Jaldips/Android-MultilevelTreeListView